# Can I handle onTap programmatically?

Tags: flutter

My problem is ususally the GestureDetector need we use hand to touch it . But now I want to call the onTap Function programmatically .

Something like below:

```dart
GlobalKey gesKey = new GlobalKey();

GestureDetector(
            key:gesKey,
            onTap: (){
             doSomething();
            },
            child: Icon(Icons.add),
          )
```

And I can do this:

```
gesKey.onTap();
```

so that I can call the doSomething().

Can I realize this ?

Comment: Why can't you just call doSomething() directly ?

Comment: @MidhunMP Because I have a dialog which cover this page , and I want to do this in my dialog , it looks like hook .

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found a way to solve this problem .

```
    FlatButton(
          child: Text("click"),
          onPressed: () {
            final GestureDetector ges = gesKey.currentWidget;
            ges.onTap();
          },
        ),
```